# CSS selector: parent class matches child class

Tags: html, css

I have a html structure which looks like this:

```html
<ul class = "one">
<li class = "one">one</li>
<li class = "two">two</li>
</ul>



<ul class = "four">
<li class = "three">three</li>
<li class = "four">four</li>
</ul>
```

I want to create a css selector which selects elements where the parent class and child class match (see also my [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/hkv5Ltp2/1/). Till now, I'm very explicit about it:

```css
.one > .one,
.two > .two
.three > .three,
.four > .four
{
  color: red
}
```

Is there a way to be less explicit? Something like: `if parent classes match child class`?

Comment: No there is not unfortunately.

Comment: how about with a css extension?

Comment: You mean a pre-processor...possibly but I doubt it. Even so it would still compile to what you have now. A pre-processor just makes CSS easier to write, it doesn't extend functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot select a parent with pure CSS, the  pseudo ":has" is just in draft and its not supported by any browser as today. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has

It's easy with jquery though

```
$(function() {
  $("li").each(function(index) {
    if ($(this).parent('ul').attr('class') == $(this).attr('class')) {
      $(this).css('color', 'red')
    }

  });
})
```

[jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/81pnhg3d/)

Comment: so `:has`, if it was supported by modern browsers, would also be a solution?

Comment: yes, :has will be the "parent selector", so you could do something like: